# What is gnome-shell doing when I edit in emacs?

Tags: gnome-shell, cpu-usage

For work I run a `gnome-shell` session on a RedHat 7.8 virtual machine.  I do all my work in an `emacs` window.

In an `xterm` running `top`, I see that `gnome-shell` has a burst of activity whenever I do something in `emacs`. It jumps from 2% CPU to 20-50% CPU when I scroll in `emacs`. It also stays at 10-20% CPU when I compile within `emacs`.

I thought `gnome-shell` was just a window manager, and would only do stuff when windows got moved around.  Apparently it does things even when windows don't move.  So, what does `gnome-shell` do?

Comment: As systemd or anything related to Red Hat, it always does more than it should. No wonder Gnome's the hoggiest Destop Manager even if it allows you to do very little. Also, a server (you're using RedHat) shouldn't have such DE, but a lightweight one like XFCE, bare XFWM or even ICEWM to reduce useless over-complexity thus attack vectors.